# What is the max number of custom fields allowed in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I have searched all over the internet to find this out. I am gathering statistical information on clients and vendors. Each field will contain many different types of data but mainly character data (varchar(max)).

Answer (score 3):

SugarCRM places no limits on the number of custom fields that you can have. However, the database being used will have limits. For example, MySQL will have a limit of 4095 columns (4096 minus the default id_c column in the custom table). Keep in mind that the real limit will be the max row size so if you need hundreds of columns be sure to define as small of a column size as you can.

More info on MySQL limits can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html

If you were to ever run into the max then you can always create a new module and do a 1-to-1 relationship with the module that you need more fields for.